# "Call of overloaded FUNCTION is ambiguous" (Conversion Constructor C++)

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm trying to implement a conversion constructor in my c++ Point class and I am receiving the error "call of overloaded FUNCTION is ambiguous". What does this mean? Looking at how my instructor implemented the conversion constructor in her program I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code in the header file:

```
Point(int n);
```

Here is the code in the class file:

```
//conversion constructor - initializes the data members from a 4 digit integer number 
//(yyxx).  If the number is less than 3 digits, set the data members to 0.
Point::Point(int n)
{
    int numDigits = 1;
    int temp = n; //temp variable to manipulate n while finding numDigits

    //while loop to find out how many digits
    while(temp/10 > 0)
    {
        numDigits++;
        temp = temp/10;
    }

    if(numDigits < 3)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    else if(numDigits == 3)
    {
        x = n%10;
        y = n/10;
    }
    else    //must be 4 digits
    {
        int y1 = n/10/10/10%10;
        int y2 = n/10/10%10;
        int x1 = n/10%10;
        int x2 = n%10;

        stringstream ss;
        ss << y1 << y2;
        string intStr1 = ss.str();

        ss << x1 << x2;
        string intStr2 = ss.str();

        x = std::stoi(intStr2);
        y = std::stoi(intStr1);

    }
}
```

and here is code in the driver file:

```
//conversion constructor
    Point x(123);
    Point y(1234);
    Point z(12);
    cout << "conversion constructor: 3 digits:           " << x.orderedPair() << endl;
    cout << "conversion constructor: 4 digits:           " << y.orderedPair() << endl;
    cout << "conversion constructor: less than 3 digits: " << z.orderedPair() << endl;
```

Any ideas what I should do to fix this?

Edit:
-Full output of error message:

```
cd 'C:\Users\npods\Documents\CSC240\C\Point'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/npods/Documents/CSC240/C/Point'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/point.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/npods/Documents/CSC240/C/Point'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:23:16: error: call of overloaded 'Point(int)' is ambiguous
     Point x(123);
                ^
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
point.h:25:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int)
     Point(int n);            //conversion constructor
     ^~~~~
point.h:24:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(const Point&)
     Point(const Point& old); //copy constructor
     ^~~~~
point.h:22:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int, int)
     Point(int x = 0, int y = 0); //default constructor &
     ^~~~~
main.cpp:24:17: error: call of overloaded 'Point(int)' is ambiguous
     Point y(1234);
                 ^
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
point.h:25:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int)
     Point(int n);            //conversion constructor
     ^~~~~
point.h:24:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(const Point&)
     Point(const Point& old); //copy constructor
     ^~~~~
point.h:22:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int, int)
     Point(int x = 0, int y = 0); //default constructor &
     ^~~~~
main.cpp:25:15: error: call of overloaded 'Point(int)' is ambiguous
     Point z(12);
               ^
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
point.h:25:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int)
     Point(int n);            //conversion constructor
     ^~~~~
point.h:24:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(const Point&)
     Point(const Point& old); //copy constructor
     ^~~~~
point.h:22:5: note: candidate: Point::Point(int, int)
     Point(int x = 0, int y = 0); //default constructor &
     ^~~~~
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:69: build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/npods/Documents/CSC240/C/Point'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/npods/Documents/CSC240/C/Point'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 968ms)
```

Comment: Aside from the rest of your question: `else if(numDigits = 3)`. Thats a typo that will eventually bite you :). Ideally your IDE should show a warning here.

Comment: At this point its very hard to tell you what the problem is. If the overload is ambiguous that means that there has to be at least another constructor which is not shown here. Also The error message contains useful information about what the other possible constructors are that the compiler tried and couldnt decide. So it would be a good idea to include those in the post.

Comment: @YanickSalzmann Thank you for pointing that out I fixed the ==. I edited the post with the full error message it seems to say all my constructors are a "candidate". Edit: also just want to point out that I tested all my other constructors by themselves and everything is working except for the conversion constructor

Comment: When you call `Point(123)` two calls of constructor match: `Point(int)` and `Point(int = 0, int = 0)`. Second version matches because second argument has default value `0`, so it is equivalent to call `Point p(123,0)`. Just remove `Point(int)` definition.

Comment: Okay so the Point(int = 0, int = 0) can be my default, parameterized, and conversion constructor all in one then?

Comment: Digits? What do digits have to do with points? Do your users demand this dangerous and counterintuitive interface because they are too lazy to type `Point(1,2,3,4)`?

Comment: @n.m. lol no my instructor likes to come up with weird requirements for whatever reason. Why anybody would ever want to enter a point as (yyxx) is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructors conflict with each other:

```
Point::Point(int x = 0, int y = 0);
Point::Point(int n);
```

And the compiler cannot choose which one to call.
Perhaps, some separation will help:

```
Point::Point(); // default
Point::Point(int x, int y);
Point::Point(int n);
```